# How to copy multiple blob containers from one storage account to another storage account(different subscriptions)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I've to copy multiple blob containers(each container has multiple files) from one storage account to another storage account.The hierarchy is below:

Container 1

- Folder 1

  - file x
  - file y
- Folder 2

  - file x
  - file y
    Container 2
- Folder 1

  - file x
  - file y
- Folder 2

  - file x
  - file y
    (Have around 50 containers)
    Here's what I've tried:
    a)Used ADF template.The copy operation is unable to copy data(Folder 1,Folder2 and files under the folders) inside the containers.
    b)AzCopy - cannot use it since it does'nt copies archive file.

Is there any other way to perform this operation?

Comment: You mean you want to copy the call the containers/files in source and auto create the sink containers to receive them  by data factory?

Comment: yes.Auto create in sink with all the folders and files

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't create containers via ADF, so you'll need some other mechanism to do that, like an Azure Function that leverages the Storage SDK. Once the container exists, you could use Copy activity with binary source and sink datasets to easily copy the contents for a container.

Answer (score 3):

In Data Factory, we can copy all the folder/files in one container to another container by binary format. I have answered the same question in Stack overflow, you can search that easily.

Settings like this:
[image]

But we can not auto create the container in sink with all the folders and files! Data Factory doesn't support create the container.

Comment: So if I have to transfer files,need to create containers on the sink side.

Comment: @Van_jss No, we can't. Data Factory doesn't support create container!