# Unable to copy the multiple containers from one subscription storage account to another subscription another storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

I know there are few ways to copy the containers from one subscription storage account to another storage account.

1. using azcopy tool but I do not have access to SAS to generate and use for above activity
2. Through Storage explorer, can't copy manually because there are 100's of containers.
3. Trying through ADF, can't find the multiple containers option in the browse option of File path:

[image]

Could anyone help me on how to select multiple containers or select all containers in a storage account and copy to another subscription storage account using ADF or any other technique?

Note:

1. I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671911/how-to-copy-multiple-blob-containers-from-one-storage-account-to-another-storage) in SO but same UI is not in my ADF pipeline and there is no complete steps to do that process.
2. The files are in excel format inside the contianer

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple containers to copy, you can add multiple Copy activities or utilize dynamic content and parameters to iterate through the containers.

**Define pipeline parameters:**

Define pipeline parameters that will hold the information about the source and destination containers. For example, you can create parameters like **SourceContainerName** and **DestinationContainerName.**

**Use dynamic content in Copy activity:**

In the Copy activity, specify the source and destination containers using dynamic content referencing the pipeline parameters. For example, you can use

`@pipeline().parameters.SourceContainerName` for the source container and

`@pipeline().parameters.DestinationContainerName` for the destination container.

**Iterate through containers:**

Add a ForEach activity to the pipeline. Configure the ForEach activity to iterate over a list of container names or any other suitable mechanism for obtaining the container names dynamically. For example, you can use an array variable or retrieve the container names from a data source like a SQL table.

**Set item in parameters:**

Inside the ForEach activity, set the value of the SourceContainerName and DestinationContainerName parameters for each iteration. You can set the parameter values using dynamic content, such as `@item()` or `@{item().ContainerName}.` The item() function or `item().ContainerName` represents the current container being iterated.

[image]

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.**